# For forwarded call, can Twilio trace the original number the caller dialled to?

Tags: twilio

Example: a caller called phone A, phone A forward to Twilio Number.

Does the payload in Twilio request **contains phone A number**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not consistently, it depends on what the carrier sends Twilio.

TwiML™ for Programmable Voice

[https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#request-parameters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#twilios-request-to-your-application)

"ForwardedFrom
This parameter is set only when Twilio receives a forwarded call, but its value depends on the caller's carrier including information when forwarding.

Not all carriers support passing this information."